# Get value of input field after random JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that chooses a random list item and inside that list item has an input field. The goal is for the user to fill out the fields and then press a button to select a random list item and display the value of that input field inside that list item.

Right now I have the random function working, it selects a random list item but I am having trouble displaying the value on the input field. It seems like the browser can't recognize what the user has typed into the input field because all the console spits out is `<li><input type='text'></li>`

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><input type='text'></li>
    <li><input type='text'></li>
    <li><input type='text'></li>
</ul>

<button id="randomize">randomize</button>

<p id="result">hello</p>
```

JS:

```
var randomize = document.getElementById("randomize");
var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

randomize.addEventListener("click", randomizeIt);

function randomizeIt () {
    var randomItem = listItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * listItems.length)];
    result.innerHTML = randomItem.value;
    console.log(randomItem);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxqh191L/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to grab the `childNode` (which is the input element).

```
result.innerHTML = randomItem.childNodes[0].value;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxqh191L/2/)